# Centos 6.4: Screen resolution forced at 1024x768, after nvidia drivers: 848x480

Tags: linux, centos, nvidia-graphics-card

I recently tried installing CentOS 6.4 on my (formerly Windows) workstation. Installation worked fine, but afterwards the screen resolution was stuck at 1024x768(screen should be able to handle 1680x1050).

I thought it was some kind of problem with the drivers, so I switched to the nvidia drivers(trying both the EPEL package installation method as well as just downloading the driver from the nvidia site and installing it that way(used http://pyrx.sourceforge.net/blog/103-installing-nvidia-driver-on-centos-6 for that one)), both methods have the same result though: my max resolution is now 848x480. I tried googling for an answer, but I haven't found a method that works yet. Can anyone help me fix this problem?

**Specs**

**Graphics card:** Geforce 9800GT

**CPU:** Intel i5 660

Answer (score 1):

Log in as root:

```
$gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf


Section "Screen"
Identifier  "Default Screen"
DefaultDepth    24
Option  "UseDisplayDevice" "DFP"
Subsection  "Display"
   Modes    "1680x1050" "1280x720" "720x480"
EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Try modifying the modes to your desired resolution and restart the system. Please take a backup of the file before editing. Not sure it will work for you. It worked for me.